# How to transition from a bulk to a cut?

Tags: workout, calories, cutting, bulking, bmr

I have a quick question and it mainly revolves around the macros for transitioning from a bulk to a cut.

So when someone reaches their desired weight / goal from a bulk and they decide to cut to take off body fat for more muscle definition, obviously their BMR is going to increase since they weigh more (right?). My question is, does that mean when someone decides to cut do they go into a calorie deficit based off the *new* BMR? while maintaining protein, decreasing carbohydrates, and decreasing a little on fats while continuing the same workout program? OR does it mean eating at a *new* BMR from the weight put on from the bulk and doing NO calorie deficit or surplus and hitting cardio to shave of calories to create a deficit while maintaining the same workout?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're worrying way too much about the BMR but leave it the same as original. The reason being your calorie deficit should be around 1000 calories a day compared to your bulk(based on average person bumping diet up by 500 from maintenance, and vice versa for bulk), so your new BMR shouldn't affect this much unless you gained like 50 lbs. Make sure to not transition right to a cut, but do a maintanence period for a few weeks, allow your body to rest and stabilize, then reduce calories. This will help reduce muscle loss too . If you keep BMR the same, it'll help you lose more weight any the end, which is nice because typically cutting slows down over time. Original BMR will start fat loss out slowly.

Comment: Ok, I have a quick question. Do you mean original BMR as in for example if my maintenance calories are 2,500 and I bulk by eating 2,800 calories and then once I get done with the bulk I should go into a deficit based off the 2,500 even though I would have put on more weight?